# If $P_1$ and $P_2$ are two normal Sylow $p$-subgroup of a group $G$ and $x$ belongs to $P_1$ and $y$ belongs to $P_2$ then show that $xy=yx$

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

This is the question that the picture shows.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5AHn.jpg)

Comment: any two sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate,so a group has only one normal $p$-Sylow subgroup.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $M,N \unlhd G$ and $M \cap N=1$, then $mn=nm$ for every $m \in M, n \in N$. Why?

Well, if $m \in M, n \in N$, then $m^{-1}n^{-1}mn=m^{-1}(n^{-1}mn) \in M$, since $M$ is normal. And also $m^{-1}n^{-1}mn=(m^{-1}n^{-1}m)n \in N$, since $N$ is normal. So $m^{-1}n^{-1}mn \in M \cap N=1$, and it follows that $m^{-1}n^{-1}mn=1$ being equivalent to $mn=nm$.

Now back to your question, if $P_1 \in Syl_{p_1}(G)$ and $P_2 \in Syl_{p_2}(G)$ are both *normal* for *different* primes $p_1$ and $p_2$, then of course $P_1 \cap P_2=1$ (use Langrange's Theorem - a non-trivial element cannot have both an order a power of $p_1$ and an order a power of $p_2$). Hence the general statement above concludes the proof.